# call an API to copy a file from one location to another

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

First of all I'm sorry for not providing any coding snippets. That's because I haven't tried it, I just want to clear my logic first. Is it possible to call an API to copy a file from one location to another, For example, passing the file name as a parameter.

My second question is, Is it good practise to run a windows service on a button click to copy a file from one location to another? For example if I have three severs, Windows service in sever 2(inside the domain) acting as the middle man to copy a file from sever 1 (inside the domain) when an application from server 3 (outside the domain) requests it. The server 3 is public facing and multiple users can request the service of the windows service at the same time? Is this possible? Sorry for the long question. any help given is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What ever you are trying to do this seams to be an extremely inefficient way to do it.

Comment: @Filip Is there a better way to do this? If so please suggest. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you want server 2 to be part of the DMZ and S1 to be in a private network and S3 on a public network. This makes sense from a security standpoint. But with 3 different machines there is also a problem of safe  communication. I don't see much benefit if it all runs on a single machine that can access the same stuff anyway. So some custom way of making the three windows machines communicate might create a security risk but this depends on how much resources you want to dedicate to it and how good do you plan to test. So if it was me I would most likely run an IIS middle man to do the copying. There you can set up the ports, HTTPS, ip whitelist, privileges and so on, much easier and the tooling is better.
It's easy to make it copy files from one machine to another in a network since all paths are just strings. The problem is isolating files you don't want to be copied. Identifying files with local id might be better since then you only allow access to the stuff you want and limiting the access to files also a special directory to copy from with no write access is a must. You could in theory just make you api return a file and let the client do what ever it wants with it but then you might louse a bit of performance.